# Toggle Class from one to another from another link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following html code

```
<a href="javascript:">
    <img class="remove" src="images/remove.png" />
</a>
<div class="content">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>We are Sydney Wedding Photographers and have ...</p>
</div>
```

which looks like this

[image]

Now, after clicking in 'X' image, 'content' div should and hide and show. But 'X' image should trigger this thing.

Comment: Which part are you having problems with after googling for "hide div javascript"?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: "'content' div should and hide and show." - what does that mean?

Comment: Class named "content" should hide after clicking link that i mentioned above. And same class should be shown clicking same link.

Comment: I am trying to edit this question but link is not available.

Comment: And special thanks for VOTE DOWN :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.remover').click(function() {
      $('.content').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.remove { cursor: pointer; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img class="remove" src="images/remove.png" />
<div class="content">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>We are Sydney Wedding Photographers and have ...</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont have any knowledge in js. Please elaborate this thing.

Comment: @Sushan check my updated code now

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Jquery toggle() function.I have done on the button click you can write the same in link click event.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#link").click(function() {
                $('.content').toggle();
                return false;
            });

        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <button id="link"   ></button>


<div class="content">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>We are Sydney Wedding Photographers and have ...</p>
</div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hasn't `.toggle` been deprecated in jQuery

Comment: @Paulie_D yes you are right! From version [1.8](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/)